# Self Hosted ASP.NET Core 2.0: TagHelper doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have ASP.NET Core 2.0 website, which is hosted in a .NET Core console / service. I have implemented  a easy custom TagHelper. The TagHelper works fine, when I started the ASP.NET Core website directly from VS2017. When i start the .NET Core console host, which has hosted the asp.net page, the tag helper doesnt work.

I have try to register the TagHelper in the _ViewImports.cshtml and also directly in the view as self (Home/Index).

My custom TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("time")]
public class TimeTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent($"<h1>{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}</h1>");
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using SelfHosted.Website
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper SelfHosted.Website.TagHelpers.*, SelfHosted.Website
```

The TimeTagHelper intellisense in VS2017 work fine:
[TimeTagHelper in Index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoyyQ.png)

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/roeb/DotNetCoreSamples). The TagHelper is implemented in SelfHosted.Website and used in /Home/Index. It works perfect when the SelfHosted.Website started directly. But it doesnt work, when i start the Website from SelfHostes.Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ... I found the answer and documented here.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2216#issuecomment-332751869